# Automating an SEC filing search for a watch list of comopanies

Tags: automation, report, finance

Mainly looking for ideas. I have a list of about 50-100 companies that I would like to monitor. Specifically looking at their SEC filings, I would like to be able to automate a process that would give me a daily/weekly report with all filings from companies on my watch list for the previous day. I know that the SEC has an API that may be useful for this, but curious about the best way to approach this.